# Prolog syntax error: illegal start of term

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

So I'm trying to test my the predicate `reduce/4` defined as following:

```
:- op(20,xfy,?=).

reduce(R,X ?=Y,P,Q) :-
    R=rename,
    regle(X ?=Y,R),
    length(P,N),
    trouve(Y,P,N,M),
    remove(N,M,P,Q).
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
?- reduce(rename,X ?= Y,[?=(X,Y),?=(f(a),g(Z)),?=(X,a)],Q].

ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal start of term
ERROR: reduce(rename,X ?= Y,[?=(X,Y),?=(f(a),g(Z)),?=(X,a)],
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: Q] .
```

I'm new to Prolog so maybe it is something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `]` instead of `)` to close the bracket of `reduce`

```
reduce(rename,X ?= Y,[?=(X,Y),?=(f(a),g(Z)),?=(X,a)],Q].
%     ^open                                           ^close
```

You can fix this with:

```
?- reduce(rename,X ?= Y,[?=(X,Y),?=(f(a),g(Z)),?=(X,a)],Q).
```

I cannot validate if this solves your problem, because you did not provide a definition for `regle/2`, etc. But the fact that I get a semantic error, seems to solve the syntax error nevertheless.